# MySQL modify data issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending a parameter through URL like:
domain-name.com/Edit-user.php?reg_no=NV000003
and retrieving data into in textfields for reg_no NV000003 from database.
It is fine here but when I click on modify button and submit form by using below code:

```
<?php
if(/$_POST){
$query=mysql_query("update table-name set 
    NAME = '".(/$_REQUEST['name'])."',
    EMAIL = '".(/$_REQUEST['email'])."'
    where field-name = 'particular-value'
    ");
    ?>
```

It is updating the data table but with empty values in all fields.
May be I am missing somthing. Any idea Plsss?

my form is

```
   <form action="" method="post" id="modifystndt" name="modifystndt"> 
   <table> <tbody> <tr> <td width="200px">Name of Student:</td> 
   <td width="400px"><strong><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $NAME; ?>"></strong></td> </tr>
   <tr> <td>E-mail :</td> <td><strong><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $EMAIL; ?>"></strong></td> </tr> 
   <tr> <tbody> <table> </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) — assuming all those bogus `/` are just a failed attempt to format code.

Comment: Did you checked is there any value in `$_REQUEST['name']`

Comment: I have put the "/" here because it was giving warning while posting code with $ here. So pls avoid "/".
@ User016, yes all filds are there with value. It only gets empty after submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     $query=mysql_query("update table-name set 
NAME = '".$_REQUEST['name']."',
EMAIL = '".$_REQUEST['email']."'
where `field-name` = 'particular-value'
");
```

as i can see in your form there is many errors .

- you dont close table, tbody, tr ,inputs tags.
- you used same name and same id for both inputs of `NAME` and `email`.

change the input of email to

```
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $EMAIL; ?>" />
```

**EDIT2:**

try this

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['modifystndt'])){
 $query=mysql_query("update table-name set 
 NAME = '".$_POST['name']."',
 EMAIL = '".$_POST['email']."'
 where field-name = 'particular-value'
 ");
 ?>
```

your form :

```
   <form action="" method="post" id="modifystndt" name="modifystndt"> 
 <table> <tbody> <tr> <td width="200px">Name of Student:</td> 
 <td width="400px"><strong><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $NAME; ?>" /></strong></td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>E-mail :</td> <td><strong><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $EMAIL; ?>" /></strong></td> </tr> 
</tbody> </table> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
```

Comment: I have put the "/" here because it was giving warning while posting code with $ here. So pls avoid "/". @ User016, yes all filds are there with value. It only gets empty after submitting form.

Comment: It is updating values so no prob with where clause. It is updating every field with null value although I can see the values in all text fields before submitting form.

Comment: can you post your form ?

Comment: [code]<form action="" method="post" id="modifystndt" name="modifystndt">
 <table>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td width="200px">Name of Student:</td>
        <td width="400px"><strong><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $NAME; ?>"></strong></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>E-mail :</td>
        <td><strong><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $EMAIL; ?>"></strong></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
<tbody>
<table>
</form>
[/code]

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected those but still stuck.
When I echo $_REQUEST['name'] before executing query, this prints no value. It mean all form inputs value is being flush on submitting it.
Any idea?

Comment: Thank you so much dear I am emotional :). was making same mistake. I had same id and name for all inputs. Big copy paste mistake. LOL
Thank you and thanks to all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If your form method is POST, you can retrieve your data with the array $_POST.

```
$query=mysql_query("update table-name set 
   NAME = '".$_POST['name']."',
   EMAIL = '".$_POST['email']."'
   where `field-name` = 'particular-value'
");
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandre got sol.

Comment: To help the next visitor of this page, you must say it is the right solution